# ftsearch returning empty docs

Tags: lotus-notes

Have a strange one.  I'm doing a NotesDatabase.ftsearch and it's returning 3 doc when it should return one.  Additionally, 2 of the docs are empty/null.

My query is simple: field contact="John Smith" field form="Contact"

When I issue the query in the view search in the Notes client, I get the one doc I expect.  Lotus Script, tho, is returning 3 docs (I'm walking through the debugger) and the first 2 don't have an values in any of the fields (in fact, "Items" is empty), yet they're being returned to the DocCollection from the ftsearch as legit hits.  My solution at this point is to check which doc has a non-empty "Items" field.  Any thoughts, ideas on what could be causing this?

thanks
clem

Here is the debug from the search using: `SET CONFIG Debug_FTV_Search=1`

```
[04FC:0092-1274] Query: FIELD firstname = "Joe" AND FIELD lastname ="Customer" and field form ="Contact" 
[04FC:0092-1274] Engine Query: ("Joe"@F215 * "Customer"@F216 * "Contact"@F206) 
[04FC:0092-1274] GTR query performed in 68 ms. 3 documents found    
[04FC:0092-1274] 0 documents disualified by deletion 
[04FC:0092-1274] 0 documents disqualified by ACL 
[04FC:0092-1274] 0 documents disqualified by IDTable 
[04FC:0092-1274] 0 documents disqualified by NIF 
[04FC:0092-1274] Results marshalled in 1 ms. 3 documents left 
[04FC:0092-1274] OUT FTGSearch error = 0 
[04FC:0092-1274] FTGSearch: found=3, returned=3, start=0, count=0, limit=0 
[04FC:0092-1274] Total search time 69 ms. 
[04FC:0092-135C] IN FTGCloseSearch 
[04FC:0092-1290] IN FTGSearch
```

Comment: Do you get the same results if you put FIELD in uppper case. Also put an AND/OR between the first and second search.

Comment: opps, sorry I DID have 'and' in there.  I tried uppercasing 'field' and 'and' but that didn't make a difference.  Same result.  thanks, tho.

Comment: If the NSF is on a server then type the following at the domino console (and update question with output after searching. Change to 0 when done).  
SET CONFIG Debug_FTV_Search=1

Comment: [04FC:0092-1274] Query: FIELD firstname = "Joe" AND FIELD lastname ="Customer" and field form ="Contact"
[04FC:0092-1274] Engine Query: ("Joe"@F215 * "Customer"@F216 * "Contact"@F206)
[04FC:0092-1274] GTR query performed in 68 ms. 3 documents found

Comment: [04FC:0092-1274] 0 documents disualified by deletion
[04FC:0092-1274] 0 documents disqualified by ACL
[04FC:0092-1274] 0 documents disqualified by IDTable
[04FC:0092-1274] 0 documents disqualified by NIF
[04FC:0092-1274] Results marshalled in 1 ms. 3 documents left
[04FC:0092-1274]  OUT FTGSearch error = 0
[04FC:0092-1274] FTGSearch: found=3, returned=3, start=0, count=0, limit=0
[04FC:0092-1274] Total search time 69 ms.
[04FC:0092-135C] IN FTGCloseSearch
[04FC:0092-1290] IN FTGSearch

Answer (score 4):

I'm going out on a bit of a limb here, but I think those are documents that you (or your agent if that's how your code is running) doesn't have access to. Have your code check NotesDocument.IsValid() for those documents.  It's probably going to come back as false.

If I'm right, just add that check to your code to weed out those docs.  Or, if you're surprised that there are documents that you don't have access to, give yourself Full Access Admin privileges and re-run the code. That should get you those document so you can check out the Reader and/or Author fields and figure out why you're not seeing them.

Comment: Based on the debug output they have access to the documents (0 disqualified), but it's possible they may not have access to the underlying fields. So your suggestions are the best way to go first. Failing that, I would use NotesPeek to physically look at the document, then after that recreate the FT index from scratch.

Comment: Hey Rich!  You're right -- isValid is false.  To weed out the bad docs,  I started using [ if Not( IsEmpty(doc.items)  ) ] but it would be cleaner to use isValid.  Seems like that should be in every piece of code!  I'll also recreate the index.  Many thanks all!  Clem

Comment: Don't forget to up vote Richard and marked the question solved.

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that sometimes there is something I call "strange docs" in a database.
You can get them using a view (getnextdocument), using a ftsearch or various other ways.

For views I found out, that these strange documents mostly come from outdated view indices. Same for ftsearches.
In that cases rebuilding the view indices or the ft indices usually made the documents disappear. But: usually you dont want to rebuild view indices before each run of an agent like this.

Thats why all my code, that runs through any kind of documents first checks three things: doc.isdeleted (sometimes deletion stubs are returned), doc.isvalid AND isempty(doc.items). And in one database I even had to wrap the isempty in an error handler, as this call caused an error.

I found out that omitting only one of these checks could mean to still get strange docs processed. 
As this happened quite often to me for different customers on different databases i wrote a little function IsDocValid that i always call when running through collections.

```
Function IsDocValid( doc as NotesDocument ) as Boolean
  Dim blnValid as Boolean
  blnValid = False
  On Error Goto ErrorHandler
  If not doc.IsDeleted then
    If doc.IsValid then
      If not isempty( doc.Items ) then
        blnValid = True
      End If
    End If
  End If
EndFunction:
  IsDocValid = blnValid
ErrorHandler:
  Resume EndFunction
End Function
```

In my loop I use this like:

```
Set doc = .....
If IsDocValid( doc ) then
  'Do the processing
End If
```

Comment: Very helpful function! We use a similar function in our projects too because of the sometimes occurring "weird" documents.